# UIView Re-Appear on Screen as it Leaves the Other Side?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I have a UIView called `clouds`.  It currently moves to the right of the screen, and once all of it has left, it reappears on the left side.

How do I make it re-appear on the left side as it leaves on the right?  So when it begins to leave on the right side, the bit which just disappeared reappears on the left side.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    movement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(moving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    cloudsMovement = 2;

}

-(void)platformMovement{
    clouds.center = CGPointMake(clouds.center.x + cloudsMovement, clouds.center.y);

}

-(void)moving{

    if (clouds.center.x < -11){
        clouds.center = CGPointMake(330, clouds.center.y);
    }
    if (clouds.center.x > 330){
        clouds.center = CGPointMake(-11, clouds.center.y);
    }

    [self platformMovement];

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bit unusual to answer my own question, but to help any other beginners like myself, this is the solution I came up with:

Create another UIView (I called this clouds2).
Move it off-screen to the left, and animate it as the original UIView (clouds1).
Adjust the numbers a bit so when the WHOLE of the image leaves the screen, it re-appears on the left.  Kind of like a converyor belt system.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    movement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(moving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    cloudsMovement = 2;
}

-(void)platformMovement{
    clouds1.center = CGPointMake(clouds1.center.x + cloudsMovement, clouds1.center.y);

    clouds2.center = CGPointMake(clouds2.center.x + cloudsMovement, clouds1.center.y);

}

-(void)moving{

    if (clouds1.center.x > 470){
        clouds1.center = CGPointMake(-150, clouds1.center.y);
    }

    if (clouds2.center.x > 470){
        clouds2.center = CGPointMake(-150, clouds2.center.y);
    }

    [self platformMovement];

}
```

Comment: This would have been my suggestion.